# MSSQL create a dynamic column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a column which created a reference for the user.
it has a fixed string part and an identity type which will increase as the table is used.
I got below code, but it does not work:

```
alter table dbo.DPC_fact_MAIN
add [REFERENCE] nvarchar(10) not null
constraint REF_GEN default concatenate('DPC#', IDENTITY(1,1))
```

criteria here is that a similar function like Identity is needed, as if the table was emptied it would start from 'DPC#1' again.

any help?

Comment: Use A computed column for this on the `IDENTITY`. `IDENTITY` can't be part of a constraint definition.

Comment: Constraints are meant to constraint. You are asking how to *compute* a value instead. Use a separate computed column that concatenates the prefix and the ID value. Better yet, since it looks like you want a sequence number instead of record identity, use a separate `SEQUENCE` object you can reset as needed